# Increasing sequence and converging to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $x_{0}$ is between $(-1,0)$ and
$$x_{n} = \sqrt{x_{n+1} + 1} - 1$$
for all natural $n$. Prove that  $x_{n}$ is increasing and converging to zero as $n$ grows.

Can someone please help me start this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Induction to prove it is increasing

Comment: Shouldn't the equation be $-x_n = \sqrt{x_{n+1}+1}$? Otherwise $x_{n+1}$ is not defined for $x_n \lt 0$.

Comment: the sequence is x_n = √ [x_(n+1) +1] - 1. I forgot to put minus 1 after the radical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $x_n$ is increasing:
\begin{align*}
x_n &= \sqrt{x_{n+1}-1} \implies x_{n+1} = (x_n+1)^2 - 1 = x_n^2 + 2x_n \\
\implies x_{n+1} - x_n &= x_n(x_n+1) > 0 \qquad \text{where $-1 \lt x_n \lt 0$} \end{align*}

Also, if $x_n$ converges to $x$ we have $$x = \sqrt{x+1}-1 \implies x^2 -x = 0 \implies x = 0 \text{ or } -1$$

And from above work we have $x_{n+1} = x_n(x_n + 2) \lt 0$ for all $-1 \lt x_n \lt 0$.

So $x_n$ is increasing and bounded and thus converges to $0$ when $-1 \lt x_0 \lt 0$